# Bind jQuery click event only to certain buttons

Tags: jquery

I have a website which create various inputs dynamically.

I have 3 specific inputs which I would like to call a JQuery function when clicked.

```
<input type="button" name="Finish" value="Finish">
<input type="button" name="Update" value="Update">
<input type="button" name="Cancel" value="Cancel">
```

Was using this code:

```
jQuery(":button").click(function(){
    //Do summat
}):
```

but this was making all the inputs on the page call the function when I only want the 3 inputs above to call the function. Is this possible?

uggers

Answer (score 9):

Give them a class name and use this one in the selector. E.g. `class="clickyButton"` and `$('.clickyButton').click(function() { /* your code *) });`

---

On a side-note, there is no need to write `jQuery` instead of `$`. If you don't want $ in the global namespace for some reason (and thus called `$.noConflict();`), you can still wrap your code in a function containing `$` mapped to jQuery:

```
(function($) {
    /* your code using $ here */
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 5):

Use a parent element to scope your buttons properly

HTML

```
<div id="my-group">
    <input type="button" name="Finish" value="Finish">
    <input type="button" name="Update" value="Update">
    <input type="button" name="Cancel" value="Cancel">
</div>

<div id="not-my-group">
    <input type="button" name="Finish" value="Finish">
    <input type="button" name="Update" value="Update">
    <input type="button" name="Cancel" value="Cancel">
</div>
```

JS

```
$("#my-group :button").click(function(){
    alert('foobar');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wpELC/2/

Using the parent selector `#my-group` will let you target only specific button groups.

Answer (score 2):

Use class to identify what action you want to take.

```
<input class="Finish" type="button" name="Finish" value="Finish">
<input class="Update" type="button" name="Update" value="Update">
<input class="Cancel" type="button" name="Cancel" value="Cancel">
```

Then use the following:

```
$('.Finish').click(function() { /* Finish code */ });
$('.Update').click(function() { /* Update code */ });
$('.Cancel').click(function() { /* Cancel code */ });
```

Comment: Wouldn't using an id be more robust? Welcome to SO by the way!

Comment: The problem with the ID is any button clicked within the <div> would fire the click, but the OP requested specific actions.

Comment: Sorry, I meant giving an id to each button and using that instead of the classes. I feel like it would be more robust since an id must be unique.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be more "selective":

```
<input class="buttongroup" type="button" name="Finish" value="Finish">
<input class="buttongroup" type="button" name="Update" value="Update">
<input class="buttongroup" type="button" name="Cancel" value="Cancel">
```

Then:

```
jQuery("input.buttongroup").click (function(){
    //Do stuff
}):
```

Comment: jQuery(), not jquery() - and instead of [type=button] using jQuery's :button selector would be better (but you don't need that at all - simple '.buttongroup' is enough)

Comment: @ThiefMaster: Thanks, I didn't notice that.

Answer (score 0):

If the name attributes you have are unique, you can just use those:

```
$("input").filter(function() {
  return this.name.match(/Finish|Update|Cancel/);
}).click(function() { 
  // example of doing something
  alert($(this).val()); 
});
```

If they are not unique, you will have to add something unique to them like a class or id, as shown in other answers